# Range doesn't iterate over full range in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I'm absolutely stuck. Trying to isolate the problem for over 6 hours but can't find out what causes the issue.
I simplified my code to make it a bit clearer. I'm having a list called `values` with around 90 values in it. And I'm having a second list with lists in it called `values`. Below I only showed it with only a few values in the list just to clarify the type.
My issue is that the `for x in range(header_count)` function won't do the full range it stops around iteration 60 instead of 90, and I can't figure out why.

```
    # Actual length around 1500 lists    
    values = [
        ["Any1StringA", "", "Any1StringA"],
        ["Any2StringA", "Any2StringB", "Any2StringC"],
        ["AnyStringC", "", ""]
    ]

    header = ["str1", "str", "str3"] # Actual length around 90
    header_count = len(header)


    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        result_dicts = []
        for row in values:
            header_dict = {}
            if not header_dict:
                result_dicts.append(header_dict)
                header_dict.clear()
            try:
                for x in range(header_count):
                        print(header_count, x) # Here is wond count to the full count of the header_count
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: Try removing your `try: ... except: pass`.  You are probably encountering an exception (which would break out of the `range` loop) that is then being swallowed, so you would have no way to know that an error happened.

Comment: Bare `except` blocks are a code smell because they will catch *anything*, including things like keyboard interrupts that aren't typically desired to be caught.  Additionally, `pass`ing in the exception handler can *sometimes* be fine, but here I don't see a good reason for it.

Comment: Also I'll just mention [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) since your data appears to be tabular.  Depending on what you are trying to do it may be much easier with a library like pandas.

Comment: @0x5453 I'm having the `try: ... except: pass` because of an line I skipped in the question. `header_dict[header[x]] = row[values[0].index(header[x])]` which kind of needs to handle an exception later on in the for loop. I will definitely take at a look at the try again to see if I can get rid of it but the lists have different length so it will be hard to compensate for that without a try, as I will get an index error.

Comment: @0x5453 Thank you I could make kind of work, python now iterates over the full range by adding emty strings or None to the except IndexError do it was definitely caused by that. And I will take a look at pandas. Never worked with it but saw it for data analysis and science being used.